# How do I check for quotation marks in liquid?

Tags: liquid

I am working with an input string like 'James "Jim" Smith' with a person's nickname being double quoted within a string. I have been trying to find if a person has a nickname by using the contains operator, but it never finds entries with double quotes. As an example:

```
<-- Name - James "Jim" Smith -->
{% if Name contains '\"' %}
   Do Something
{% else %}
   Always gets here
{% endif %}
```

How can I search for the literal double quote in a string using contains (or split)?

Comment: Did you try double slash ? ex: 'James \\"Jim\\" Smith'

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to escape it. The following will return true:

```
{% assign name = 'James "Jim" Smith' %}
{% if name contains '"' %}
  true
{% else %}
  false
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I tried this first and it did not work, it always returns false for '"' or for '\"' the double slash also does not work (but it was worth a try). If I search for a subset of the characters such as 'Jim' the contains statement returns true.

Comment: Strange, the above outputs true for me. try copy and paste the above into your project. and see what happens

Comment: @DaveW This was a long time ago but were you working on Shopify or something else?

Answer (score 2):

My approach to solve the problem:

```
{{ post.title | remove: '&quot;'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Liquid map I have observed `\\\"` translates into `\"`

Answer (score 0):

I have read about escaping both single and double quotes by doubling them and had some success myself doing this...

In my own example I was trying to remove quotes from a string
And the following did NOT work:

```
{{ post.title | remove: """ }}
```

However this DID work:

```
{{ post.title | remove: """" }}
```

I think that would work in your *if* statement:

```
{% if name contains '""' %}
```

But am not sure how that would work where you are assigning the string or if you need to escape it in your "assign"

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above works for you, try this. It did it for me when removing double quotes:

```
| remove '"'
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove: '"' seems working to me

Comment: Please don't post an answer just to confirm that another answer works, this is not a forum. Thank you.